# Extract specific columns from dataset, create column of NAs if it doesn't exist

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Data frame `df` has 57 columns. I later read in other csv files, each of which may have the same 57, but more likely have more or fewer columns. I take the names of the original file as:

```
df = read.csv(...)
str = colnames(df)
```

I know I can take subsets of a data frame as:

```
file = read.csv(...)
file = file[, str]
```

If the columns of `file` have the same or greater number of columns than the original 57, this will work fine. The extra columns would simply be dropped. However, if the columns of `file` are fewer than the original 57, the following error arises:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(file, , str) : undefined columns selected
```

Is there a way to take this same approach, but create columns of `NA` if the column does not exist in `file`?

EDIT: Including `dput` ouput for @akrun. I'm not familiar with `dput` so I hope this is what you were asking for:

File 1 example:

```
`structure(list(ObservationURI = c("http://resources.usgin.org/uri-gin/wygs/bhtemp/49-037-20341_182_12296/", 
"http://resources.usgin.org/uri-gin/wygs/bhtemp/49-037-20341_215_14316/", 
"http://resources.usgin.org/uri-gin/wygs/bhtemp/49-037-20341_236_16496/"
), WellName = c("1 BRADY UNIT ANADARKO E&P COMPANY LP", "1 BRADY UNIT ANADARKO E&P COMPANY LP", 
"1 BRADY UNIT ANADARKO E&P COMPANY LP"), APINo = c("49-037-20341", 
"49-037-20341", "49-037-20341"), HeaderURI = c("http://resources.usgin.org/uri-gin/wygs/well/3720341/", 
"http://resources.usgin.org/uri-gin/wygs/well/3720341/", "http://resources.usgin.org/uri-gin/wygs/well/3720341/"
), OtherID = c(3720341, 3720341, 3720341), OtherName = c(NA, 
NA, NA), BoreholeName = c(NA, NA, NA), Label = c("Temperature observation for well 3720341", 
"Temperature observation for well 3720341", "Temperature observation for well 3720341"
), Operator = c("", "", ""), LeaseName = c("", "", ""), LeaseOwner = c("", 
"", ""), LeaseNo = c("", "", ""), SpudDate = c("1900-01-01T00:00", 
"1900-01-01T00:00", "1900-01-01T00:00"), EndedDrillingDate = c("", 
"", ""), WellType = c("Oil", "Oil", "Oil"), Status = c("Producing Oil Well", 
"Producing Oil Well", "Producing Oil Well"), CommodityOfInterest = c("", 
"", ""), StatusDate = c("1973-05-03T00:00:00", "1973-05-03T00:00:00", 
"1973-05-03T00:00:00"), Function = c(NA, NA, NA), Production = c(NA, 
NA, NA), ProducingInterval = c(NA, NA, NA), ReleaseDate = c(NA, 
NA, NA), Field = c("", "", ""), OtherLocationName = c("Great Divide Basin", 
"Great Divide Basin", "Great Divide Basin"), County = c("Sweetwater", 
"Sweetwater", "Sweetwater"), State = c("WY", "WY", "WY"), PLSS_Meridians = c(NA, 
NA, NA), TWP = c("16N", "16N", "16N"), RGE = c("101W", "101W", 
"101W"), Section_ = c(11, 11, 11), SectionPart = c("NENW", "NENW", 
"NENW"), Parcel = c(NA, NA, NA), UTM_E = c(NA, NA, NA), UTM_N = c(NA, 
NA, NA), UTMDatumZone = c(NA, NA, NA), LatDegree = c(41.38696, 
41.38696, 41.38696), LongDegree = c(-108.75009, -108.75009, -108.75009
), SRS = c("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:4326"), LocationUncertaintyStatement = c("nil:missing", 
"nil:missing", "nil:missing"), LocationUncertaintyCode = c(NA, 
NA, NA), LocationUncertaintyRadius = c(NA, NA, NA), DrillerTotalDepth = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), DepthReferencePoint = c(NA, NA, NA), LengthUnits = c("ft", 
"ft", "ft"), WellBoreShape = c(NA, NA, NA), TrueVerticalDepth = c(NA, 
NA, NA), ElevationKB = c(7135, 7135, 7135), ElevationDF = c(7106, 
7106, 7106), ElevationGL = c(0, 0, 0), FormationTD = c("", "", 
""), BitDiameterCollar = c(NA, NA, NA), BitDiameterTD = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), DiameterUnits = c("", "", ""), Notes = c("Depth of measurement assumed to be equal to driller total depth (CRC-AZGS, 2013).", 
"Depth of measurement assumed to be equal to driller total depth (CRC-AZGS, 2013).", 
"Depth of measurement assumed to be equal to driller total depth (CRC-AZGS, 2013)."
), MaximumRecordedTemperature = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), MeasuredTemperature = c(182, 215, 236), CorrectedTemperature = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), TemperatureUnits = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
), TimeSinceCirculation = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), CirculationDuration = c(11, 
12, 12), MeasurementProcedure = c("Well log", "Well log", "Well log"
), CorrectionType = c(NA, NA, NA), DepthOfMeasurement = c(-99999, 
-99999, -99999), MeasurementDateTime = c("", "", ""), MeasurementFormation = c("", 
"", ""), MeasurementSource = c("Richard W. Davis: Deriving geothermal parameters from bottom-hole temperatures in Wyoming\" AAPG bulletin, V. 96, No. 8 (August 2012), pp. 1579-1592", 
"Richard W. Davis: Deriving geothermal parameters from bottom-hole temperatures in Wyoming\" AAPG bulletin, V. 96, No. 8 (August 2012), pp. 1579-1592", 
"Richard W. Davis: Deriving geothermal parameters from bottom-hole temperatures in Wyoming\" AAPG bulletin, V. 96, No. 8 (August 2012), pp. 1579-1592"
), RelatedResource = c(NA, NA, NA), CasingLogger = c(NA, NA, 
NA), CasingBottomDepthDriller = c(NA, NA, NA), CasingTopDepth = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), CasingPipeDiameter = c(NA, NA, NA), CasingWeight = c(NA, 
NA, NA), CasingWeightUnits = c(NA, NA, NA), CasingThickness = c(NA, 
NA, NA), DrillingFluid = c("", "", ""), Salinity = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), MudResistivity = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), Density = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), FluidLevel = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), pH = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Viscosity = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), FluidLoss = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), MeasurementNotes = c(NA, NA, NA), InformationSource = c("Wyoming State Geological Survey", 
"Wyoming State Geological Survey", "Wyoming State Geological Survey"
)), .Names = c("ObservationURI", "WellName", "APINo", "HeaderURI", 
"OtherID", "OtherName", "BoreholeName", "Label", "Operator", 
"LeaseName", "LeaseOwner", "LeaseNo", "SpudDate", "EndedDrillingDate", 
"WellType", "Status", "CommodityOfInterest", "StatusDate", "Function", 
"Production", "ProducingInterval", "ReleaseDate", "Field", "OtherLocationName", 
"County", "State", "PLSS_Meridians", "TWP", "RGE", "Section_", 
"SectionPart", "Parcel", "UTM_E", "UTM_N", "UTMDatumZone", "LatDegree", 
"LongDegree", "SRS", "LocationUncertaintyStatement", "LocationUncertaintyCode", 
"LocationUncertaintyRadius", "DrillerTotalDepth", "DepthReferencePoint", 
"LengthUnits", "WellBoreShape", "TrueVerticalDepth", "ElevationKB", 
"ElevationDF", "ElevationGL", "FormationTD", "BitDiameterCollar", 
"BitDiameterTD", "DiameterUnits", "Notes", "MaximumRecordedTemperature", 
"MeasuredTemperature", "CorrectedTemperature", "TemperatureUnits", 
"TimeSinceCirculation", "CirculationDuration", "MeasurementProcedure", 
"CorrectionType", "DepthOfMeasurement", "MeasurementDateTime", 
"MeasurementFormation", "MeasurementSource", "RelatedResource", 
"CasingLogger", "CasingBottomDepthDriller", "CasingTopDepth", 
"CasingPipeDiameter", "CasingWeight", "CasingWeightUnits", "CasingThickness", 
"DrillingFluid", "Salinity", "MudResistivity", "Density", "FluidLevel", 
"pH", "Viscosity", "FluidLoss", "MeasurementNotes", "InformationSource"
), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")`

File 2 example:

`structure(list(ObservationURI = c("http://resources.usgin.org/uri-gin/mags/bhtemp/UM:MA-Weston47-422036N0711640.1/", 
"http://resources.usgin.org/uri-gin/mags/bhtemp/UM:MA-Dover20-421431N0711752.1/", 
"http://resources.usgin.org/uri-gin/mags/bhtemp/UM:MA-Lincoln13-422440N0711815.1/"
), WellName = c("Weston47-USGS HDR19", "Dover20-USGS HDR19", 
"Lincoln13-USGS HDR19"), APINo = c(NA, NA, NA), HeaderURI = c("http://resources.usgin.org/uri-gin/mags/well/Weston47-USGS_HDR19/", 
"http://resources.usgin.org/uri-gin/mags/well/Dover20-USGS_HDR19/", 
"http://resources.usgin.org/uri-gin/mags/well/Lincoln13-USGS_HDR19/"
), OtherID = c("", "", ""), OtherName = c("", "", ""), BoreholeName = c(NA, 
NA, NA), Operator = c(NA, NA, NA), LeaseOwner = c(NA, NA, NA), 
    LeaseNo = c(NA, NA, NA), SpudDate = c(NA, NA, NA), EndedDrillingDate = c("", 
    "", ""), WellType = c("temporarily abandoned", "observation", 
    "observation"), Status = c("Idle", "Idle", "Idle"), CommodityOfInterest = c("Water", 
    "Water", "Water"), StatusDate = c("", "", ""), Function = c("production", 
    "monitoring", "monitoring"), Production = c(NA, NA, NA), 
    Field = c(NA, NA, NA), County = c("Middlesex", "Norfolk", 
    "Middlesex"), State = c("MA", "MA", "MA"), PLSS_Meridians = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), TWP = c(NA, NA, NA), RGE = c(NA, NA, NA), Section_ = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), SectionPart = c(NA, NA, NA), Parcel = c(NA, NA, 
    NA), UTM_E = c(NA, NA, NA), UTM_N = c(NA, NA, NA), LatDegree = c(42.3147771183, 
    42.2417748607, 42.4110851252), LongDegree = c(-71.3257301787, 
    -71.2975422044, -71.3034583949), SRS = c("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:4326", 
    "EPSG:4326"), LocationUncertaintyStatement = c("Field located on topographic map", 
    "Field located on topographic map", "Field located on topographic map"
    ), DrillerTotalDepth = c(29, 22, 20), LengthUnits = c("ft", 
    "ft", "ft"), WellBoreShape = c("Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical"
    ), TrueVerticalDepth = c(NA, NA, NA), ElevationGL = c(140, 
    150, 180), BitDiameterTD = c(72, 48, 42), DiameterUnits = c("in", 
    "in", "in"), Notes = c("", "", ""), MeasuredTemperature = c(8, 
    9, 8.5), CorrectedTemperature = c(NA, NA, NA), TemperatureUnits = c("C", 
    "C", "C"), TimeSinceCirculation = c(NA, NA, NA), CirculationDuration = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), MeasurementProcedure = c("Samples collected from spigot or faucet nearest to well.  Water run until temperature, pH or specific conductance stablized.  Temperature measured with a mercury thermometer to nearest half degree in degrees F.  Converted to degrees C for table.", 
    "Samples collected from spigot or faucet nearest to well.  Water run until temperature, pH or specific conductance stablized.  Temperature measured with a mercury thermometer to nearest half degree in degrees F.  Converted to degrees C for table.", 
    "Samples collected from spigot or faucet nearest to well.  Water run until temperature, pH or specific conductance stablized.  Temperature measured with a mercury thermometer to nearest half degree in degrees F.  Converted to degrees C for table."
    ), CorrectionType = c(NA, NA, NA), DepthOfMeasurement = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), MeasurementDateTime = c(NA, NA, NA), MeasurementFormation = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), MeasurementSource = c("Walker, Eugene H., William W. Caswell, and S. William Wandle, Jr. Hydrologic Data of the Charles River Basin", 
    "Walker, Eugene H., William W. Caswell, and S. William Wandle, Jr. Hydrologic Data of the Charles River Basin", 
    "Walker, Eugene H., William W. Caswell, and S. William Wandle, Jr. Hydrologic Data of the Charles River Basin"
    ), CasingLogger = c(" Massachusetts\". USGS Massachusetts Hydrologic-Data Report No. 19 (1977): 1-57. Print.  ftp://eclogite.geo.umass.edu/pub/stategeologist/Products/Geothermal/BoreholeTemperatureData/DataReport19.pdf\"", 
    " Massachusetts\". USGS Massachusetts Hydrologic-Data Report No. 19 (1977): 1-57. Print.  ftp://eclogite.geo.umass.edu/pub/stategeologist/Products/Geothermal/BoreholeTemperatureData/DataReport19.pdf\"", 
    " Massachusetts\". USGS Massachusetts Hydrologic-Data Report No. 19 (1977): 1-57. Print.  ftp://eclogite.geo.umass.edu/pub/stategeologist/Products/Geothermal/BoreholeTemperatureData/DataReport19.pdf\""
    ), CasingDepthDriller = c("", "", ""), CasingPipeDiameter = c("", 
    "", ""), CasingWeight = c(NA, NA, NA), CasingWeightUnits = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), CasingThickness = c(NA, NA, NA), DrillingFluid = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Salinity = c(NA, NA, NA), MudResisitivity = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Density = c(NA, NA, NA), FluidLevel = c(NA, NA, 
    NA), pH = c(NA, NA, NA), Viscosity = c(NA, NA, NA), FluidLoss = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Unnamed..66 = c(NA, NA, NA), BitDiameterCollar = c(72, 
    48, 42), Unnamed..68 = c(NA, NA, NA), InformationSource = c("Stephen Mabee, MA State Geologist, University of Massachusetts, 611 North Pleasant Street, Amherst MA 01003 413-545-2285", 
    "Stephen Mabee, MA State Geologist, University of Massachusetts, 611 North Pleasant Street, Amherst MA 01003 413-545-2285", 
    "Stephen Mabee, MA State Geologist, University of Massachusetts, 611 North Pleasant Street, Amherst MA 01003 413-545-2285"
    )), .Names = c("ObservationURI", "WellName", "APINo", "HeaderURI", 
"OtherID", "OtherName", "BoreholeName", "Operator", "LeaseOwner", 
"LeaseNo", "SpudDate", "EndedDrillingDate", "WellType", "Status", 
"CommodityOfInterest", "StatusDate", "Function", "Production", 
"Field", "County", "State", "PLSS_Meridians", "TWP", "RGE", "Section_", 
"SectionPart", "Parcel", "UTM_E", "UTM_N", "LatDegree", "LongDegree", 
"SRS", "LocationUncertaintyStatement", "DrillerTotalDepth", "LengthUnits", 
"WellBoreShape", "TrueVerticalDepth", "ElevationGL", "BitDiameterTD", 
"DiameterUnits", "Notes", "MeasuredTemperature", "CorrectedTemperature", 
"TemperatureUnits", "TimeSinceCirculation", "CirculationDuration", 
"MeasurementProcedure", "CorrectionType", "DepthOfMeasurement", 
"MeasurementDateTime", "MeasurementFormation", "MeasurementSource", 
"CasingLogger", "CasingDepthDriller", "CasingPipeDiameter", "CasingWeight", 
"CasingWeightUnits", "CasingThickness", "DrillingFluid", "Salinity", 
"MudResisitivity", "Density", "FluidLevel", "pH", "Viscosity", 
"FluidLoss", "Unnamed..66", "BitDiameterCollar", "Unnamed..68", 
"InformationSource"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")`
```

Comment: Throwing away extra columns sounds pretty draconian to me.  Can you describe more about what you are doing with your data?

Comment: The original dataframe `df` follows a "content model" which is a sort of standard for these types of datasets. The subsequent datasets I read in attempt to follow this model, but often include extra, unnecessary columns or do not live up to the standard and have fewer columns than the content model. 

In the end, all the files must have the same columns for further processing. Therefore if the column doesn't exist, it must be created, even if it is just full of NA's.

Comment: @akrun - You don't need to tell the person that you posted an answer.  They get a notification when an answer is posted.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.  You are asking them not to be biased but you post a comment directing them to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

We can read the datasets in a `list` with `fread` and use `rbindlist` from `data.table` with `fill = TRUE` and `idcol` argument to create a single `data.table` object.  The `fill = TRUE` ensure that NA elements are created for those datasets that have lesser number of columns.

```
library(data.table)
#get the files from the working directory
files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
#read files in a loop with fread and then rbind the data.tables 
rbindlist(lapply(files, fread), fill = TRUE, idcol = "grp")
```

Comment: No I think this is going in the right direction. What does `idcol = "grp"` do? Is that where my `str` variable of column names would go?

Comment: @KevinM  It is just an identifier for the dataset from which it came i.e. if we have 100 files, the id will be 1:100 where 1 is for the first dataset, 2 for second, and so on.

Comment: The error I'm getting with this approach:
`Error in rbindlist(lapply(files, fread), fill = T, idcol = "grp") : 
  Class attributes at column 3 of input list at position 3 does not match with column 3 of input list at position 1. Coercion of objects of class 'factor' alone is handled internally by rbind/rbindlist at the moment.`

Comment: @KevinM  Do you have different classes for each datasets.

Comment: No they should all be data.frame classes. The working directory contains 47 .csv files, if that information helps.

Comment: @KevinM Can you update your post with at least the head of two datasets that give the error using `dput` so that I can test it.

Comment: Ok I think I may have found the root of the first problem (could be similar ones that pop up). The column `APINo` in dataset 1 is of type `chr` but the same column in dataset 2 is of type `integer64`. I'm not sure why this is the case, and I don't know how to convert properly. As an example, the first entry in the .csv for dataset 2 is `1003199480000`. When it is read by `read.csv`, it gets converted to numeric (`1.003199e12`) and when it is read by `lapply` it gets converted to integer64 (`4.956464e-312`).